# Remove frontend scaffolding from Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel, frontend, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

I have installed `laravel/ui` from `composer` and since I am learning I tried to setup bootstrap with it so I installed bootstrap from npm and then ran `php artisan ui bootstrap`. I was able to set it up properly.

I now want to remove the installed frontend scaffolding and I couldn't find anywhere how to do it.

So far I have tried `php artisan ui none` but none is not a valid preset.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the package by running:

```
composer remove laravel/ui
```

You'll have to remove the scaffolding manually.